# How to do transaction rollback for integration tests in azure pipeline?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

We use MSDTC to rollback our transactions in order to keep database changes independent in our local environment. What can we do in azure pipeline? Can we enable MSDTC? Is there another alternative to reach our objective?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with database transactions rollback, but according to [this link](https://www.sqlshack.com/rollback-sql-rolling-back-transactions-via-the-rollback-sql-query/) and [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-transactions/), you could use command line or query to rollback transaction. If this is the case, you could use command line task, script task, or Azure SQL database deployment task, etc in Azure Pipeline to run commands, or script.

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Sorry for answering late. We needed to start the transaction before each test execution and rollback it after. So we needed to do it all in C#.  Also we should be able to run our tests in visual studio. So finally we installed an agent locally and provided MSDTC service on the same machine.